# Email each line of sql as email

Tags: php, email

This script looks fine but when i run it, the entire db is just echo'd all over the page. I didn't get any errors so not sure yet but i uploaded a spreadsheet to sql full of tasks and then each line i want to email to myself and if possible delete it after but i can manually do that anyway. The goal is just to array the email across each row.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","toor");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db("db", $con);
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tasks");
  $to = "someone@somewhere.com";
  $subject = "Results from query";
  $body = 
  "<table border='1'>
     <tr>
         <th>CustomerID:</th>
         <th>Name:</th>
         <th>CompanyCode:</th>
         <th>Country:</th>
         <th>SalesRep:</th>
         <th>City:</th>
         <th>PostalCode:</th>
  </tr>";

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['CustomerID'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['CompanyCode'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Country'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['SalesRep'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['City'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['PostalCode'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
  mysql_close($con);
  $headers = 'From: someone@example.com';
  mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
  echo 'Mail sent to $to';
?>
```

Comment: Please take some time to read [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: I think you should use `$body .= ""` inside loop not `echo`

Comment: i know i need to stop using mysql functions but it is just such a force of habbit.

Comment: trying the body modification.....

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: body @JainilNagar and still echoing the data across the page.

Comment: Put your updated code

Comment: that is it really, just took out my email and db settings

Comment: Have you replace all `echo` with and stored the content inside `$body` variable? Also, try to print `$body` before `mail()` and check for correct result and set error reporting on

Comment: printing it displayed the table in the page but no email execution, i mite need to revisit this one. something is not right.